# Write a deployment script for a react application

Tags: reactjs, deployment, sh, circleci

I am learning about the Continuous Deployment procedure. I have a process that I follow for manually deploying a ReactJS Application to a Ubuntu Server provided by Digital Ocean. The procedure I followed for a manual deployment involves the following steps:

1) SSH into the Ubuntu Server.

2) Then git clone the Github repository into the following directory on the ubuntu server: /var/www/ which contains the Frontend React project.

3) Go to the directory (/var/www/FEBookingAndCollections) and type npm install followed by npm run build. This creates the build directory (/var/www/FEBookingAndCollections/build). I am using Nginx as the Web Server which I have configured the web document root to serve the contents in the following path /var/www/FEBookingAndCollections/build

4) Check that the website is online.

I wanted to automate this process using CircleCI and Github. Inside my ReactJS application project, specifically my .circleci/config.yml. I have the following content:

```
 deploy:
    machine:
      enabled: true
    steps:
      - add_ssh_keys:
          fingerprints:

              - "16:a3:20:18:79 ..."
      - run:
          name: Deploy Over SSH
          command: |
             ssh -v root@46.121.314.160 "/var/local/deployScripts/./deployFe.sh"
```

In terms of what is happening, I want to know what I should write into the deployFE.sh file in order to automate the steps from 1 - 3. Has anyone wrote a deployment shell script before and would be able to advise? I am new in this area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is a great use case for Docker. Much easier than how you're currently trying to do it.
2. In the simplest form, `deployFe.sh` should contain the exact shell commands that you normally type manually in order to complete steps 1-3. A shell script simply automates what you would normally do at a terminal yourself.